# If G be a cyclic group of prime order p ,prove that non identity element of G is a generator of the group.

Tags: cyclic-groups

If G be a cyclic group of prime order p ,prove that non identity element of G is a generator of the group. 
Let , a be the generator of the group . Then o(a)=p ==>a^p = e, where e be the identity element . G={a,a^2,a^3,.....,a^p(=e)}.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange’s theorem?

Comment: @egreg Yes, i know Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: So, consider $\langle a\rangle$, which is a subgroup of $G$ having more than one element; hence $|\langle a\rangle|$ is a divisor of $p$ and is greater than $1$.

Comment: @egreg thanks i understand. I give you another question please solve this: prove that in a cyclic group of even order, there is exactly one element of order 2.